# How to use properties of one object in another

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I want to create my own class, lets say `Data` which will contain `File` and additional info about it:

```
Data = function(file, oneInfo, anotherInfo, moreInfo) { 
    this.file = file;
    this.property1 = oneInfo;
    this.property1 = anotherInfo;
    this.property1 = moreInfo;
};
```

But I would like to read info about file directly from my object Data, for example Data.size
I can do it (ugly) like this:

```
Data = function(file, oneInfo, anotherInfo, moreInfo) { 
    this.file = file;
    this.size = file.size;
    this.property1 = oneInfo;
    this.property1 = anotherInfo;
    this.property1 = moreInfo;
};
```

so now `Data.size` is accessible, but is there any other way which i can use to call for file properties without `Data.file.size` or my ugly version? 
Maybe some kind of inherit properties from File to Data?
Of course the `File` must be still accessible (for example for using it to send through `xhr.send()`)

Comment: *"so now `Data.size` is accessible"* No, it isn't. `Data` still has no `size`. An object created via `new Date` does, though, is that what you mean?

Comment: What is ugly about it? Is it just that you have to do this manually for each property (to the point that it gets tedious), or is there a possibility that the file will change behind your back and that you want to keep the properties in sync?

Comment: Yes, new Data object will have that property

Comment: I Just want to write only Data.size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so now `Data.size` is accessible

I'm going to assume you mean that if you do `var d = new Data(...);`, then `d.size` is accessible.

If so, you can do it (in ES5 and higher) by defining a *property accessor* via `Object.defineProperty` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) | [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.defineproperty)):

```
Object.defineProperty(Data.prototype, "size", {
    // The "getter" is called when you _get_ the value
    // You don't have to define one, though it's odd if you don't
    get: function() {
        return this.file && this.file.size;
    },
    // The "setter" is called when you _set_ the value
    // You don't have to define one; if you don't the property is read-only
    set: function(value) {
        if (this.file) {
            this.file.size = value;
        }
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
function Data(file) {
    this.file = file;
}
Object.defineProperty(Data.prototype, "size", {
    // The "getter" is called when you _get_ the value
    // You don't have to define one, though it's odd if you don't
    get: function() {
        return this.file && this.file.size;
    },
    // The "setter" is called when you _set_ the value
    // You don't have to define one; if you don't the property is read-only
    set: function(value) {
        if (this.file) {
            this.file.size = value;
        }
    }
});

// Initial setup
var f = {
    size: 10
};
var d = new Data(f);
console.log(d.size); // 10

// Changing f.size affects what you get back from d.size
f.size = 20;
console.log(d.size); // 20

// Changing d.size changes f.size
d.size = 30;
console.log(f.size); // 30
```

Obsolete JavaScript engines like the one in IE8 won't be able to handle it, but all modern ones will.

In ES2015+, you can use `class` syntax with an accessor definition:

```
class Data {
    constructor(file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    get size() {
        return this.file && this.file.size;
        // In ES2020+ you could use optional chaining:
        // return this.file?.size;
    }
    set size(value) {
        if (this.file) {
            this.file.size = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Data {
    constructor(file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    get size() {
        return this.file && this.file.size;
    }
    set size(value) {
        if (this.file) {
            this.file.size = value;
        }
    }
}

// Initial setup
const f = {
    size: 10
};
const d = new Data(f);
console.log(d.size); // 10

// Changing f.size affects what you get back from d.size
f.size = 20;
console.log(d.size); // 20

// Changing d.size changes f.size
d.size = 30;
console.log(f.size); // 30
```

Comment: Thanks, and great snippet.js, will use for sure :D

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good use case for getter properties:

```
Object.defineProperty(Data.prototype, 'size', {
   get: function () {
       return this.file.size;
   }
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty.